# Generic WCF proxy implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, lambda

I am writing a proxy to access a WCF service where we have access to both the WCF service and the client's code.

For each method in the Service contract interface I am writing a method like this.

The trouble is that there are many methods in the interface and effectively this is turning into a copy and paste exercise.

Is there a more elegant way (with lambdas?) of doing this that isn't so verbose ? I can't quick figure it out please....

```
public interface IServiceContract
{
   DataContracts.TypeA Method1(int arg1, string arg2);
   string Method2(string arg1);
   DateTime Method3();
   int Method4(DataContracts.Input1);
   // etc............
}


    public class Proxy : IServiceContract....

    public DataContracts.TypeA Method1(int arg1, string arg2)
    {
        IFileService proxy = null;
        ChannelFactory<IFileService> factory = null;
        try
        {
            factory = new ChannelFactory<IFileService>("*");
            proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            return proxy.Method1(arg1, arg2);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(proxy, factory);
        }
    }


     public List<AnOtherResultPoco> Method2(string arg1)
     {
         IFileService proxy = null;
         ChannelFactory<IFileService> factory = null;
         try
         {
             factory = new ChannelFactory<IFileService>("*");
             proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
             return proxy.Method2(args1);
         }
         finally
         {
             CloseConnection(proxy, factory);
         }
    }

    //ad inifinitum for methods,3,4,5...
```

Comment: What is different in those methods which you duplicate?

Comment: each proxy method is identical except it just calls a different method in the interface (editing question to show this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to factorize your code a bit using lambda, I suggest to write a method that looks like this:

```
...
public void ServiceCall(Action<IFileService> action)
{
    IFileService proxy = null;
    ChannelFactory<IFileService> factory = null;
    try
    {
        factory = new ChannelFactory<IFileService>("*");
        proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        return action(proxy);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection(proxy, factory);
    }
}
```

So you call your service methods this way:

```
...
List<AnOtherResultPoco> result;
MyClass.ServiceCall(p => { result = p.Method2("hello"); });
...
```

Comment: the return is void on ServiceCall(..), is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is. The anonymous method "{result = p.Method2("hello");}" will get the call return in the 'result' variable.

Comment: thanks but, return action(proxy); doesnt compile then

Comment: I did a lot of typos and edit since. I confused IFileService and IServiceContract. I am not sure this compiles right away. Please get the changed code and try again

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection.

```
    public List<MyResultType> SearchBy(string searchTerm, string method)
    {
        IFileService proxy = null;
        ChannelFactory<IFileService> factory = null;
        try
        {
            factory = new ChannelFactory<IFileService>("*");
            proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            if (!IsMethodAllowed(method))
            {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
            return (List<MyResultType>)proxy.GetType().GetMethod(method).Invoke(proxy, new object[] { searchTerm });

        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(proxy, factory);
        }
    }
```

This is another way, maybe what you are looking for.

```
    public List<MyResultType> SearchByMethod1(int a, int b)
    {
        return (List<MyResultType>)SearchBy(new object[] { a, b }, "Method1");
    }

    public List<MyResultType2> SearchByMethod2(MyResultType b)
    {
        return (List<MyResultType2>)SearchBy(new object[] { b }, "Method1");
    }

    protected object SearchBy(object[] parameters, string method)
    {
        IFileService proxy = null;
        ChannelFactory<IFileService> factory = null;
        try
        {
            factory = new ChannelFactory<IFileService>("*");
            proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            if (!IsMethodAllowed(method))
            {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
            return (List<MyResultType>)proxy.GetType().GetMethod(method).Invoke(proxy, parameters);

        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(proxy, factory);
        }
    }
```

This would not lead to having generics all over your code. It is neatly wrapped inside proxy.

Comment: how would this work for the differing result types and arguments in the interface though?

Comment: Well, by definition reflection always adds sluggihness and delayed problems. As far as i know you cannot make it that generic without then having to code somewhere else. You can substitute searchTerm with object[] (to make generic params), and you can substitute result List<MyResultType> with object. But this would postpone the implementation of proxy strong types to other code which i would not suggest. So basically this is as far as you can get if you have different result type and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but I run into the same problem today, and found an easy solution, thought I would share for future users.
So in this solution, we will make our own proxy instead of generating a service reference.

Here is the Proxy, The idea is to make it generic:

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public ChannelFactory<T> Channel { get; set; }

    public Proxy()
    {
        Channel = new ChannelFactory<T>("endpoint");
    }

    public T CreateChannel()
    {
        return Channel.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Now here is the trick :

For void methods :

```
public void Execute(Action<T> action)
{
    T proxy = CreateChannel();

    action(proxy);

    ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Close();
}
```

For return:

```
public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> function)
    {
        T proxy = CreateChannel();

        var result = function(proxy);

        ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Where the TResult is the returning type.

How to use:

```
Proxy<IService> proxy = new Proxy();
// for a void method
Proxy.Execute(prxy => prxy.Method());
// for non void method.
var result = Proxy.Execute(prxy => prxy.Method());
```

So, to sum up, here is how the proxy class should look like:

```
public class Proxy<T>
    {
        public ChannelFactory<T> Channel { get; set; }

        public Proxy()
        {
            Channel = new ChannelFactory<T>("endpoint");
        }

        public T CreateChannel()
        {
            return Channel.CreateChannel();
        }

        public void Execute(Action<T> action)
        {
            T proxy = CreateChannel();

            action(proxy);

            ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Close();
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> function)
        {
            T proxy = CreateChannel();

            var result = function(proxy);

            ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Close();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I recommend this solution for a custom wcf proxy without using any service reference, its really simple and easy.